# Cannot start a NodeJS app (Appium) on OSX El Capitan after OS upgrade

Tags: .net, node.js, macos, ssh

So I have this piece of .Net code that triggers Appium which is a NodeJS application that runs on a Mac OS. It used to work on Yosemite but stopped working after the XCode and El Capitan updates. I am trying the run the following command as part of the code:

```
ssh.RunCommand("/usr/local/bin/forever start /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js --address 0.0.0.0 --port 4723 --log-level debug --device-name \"iPhone 6\" --platform-name iOS --platform-version \"8.4\" --app \"/Applications/my.app\" --browser-name iOS -l --log /Library/Logs/Appium/current.log");
```

And I am getting "env: node: No such file or directory" in Visual Studio

```
System Policy: deny file-write-data /usr/bin/env
```

On the system.log
I guess OS X doesn't allow me to access /usr/bin/env anymore, is there any way to bypass it?
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

El Capitan added something called System Integrity Protection or "SIP". "SIP" prevents you to write in `/usr` even if you are root. However, `/usr/local` is still available and that's what your app is trying to do. But chances are `/usr/local` doesn't exist or you don't have the proper permissions.

If `/usr/local` exists already, run:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

else, follow this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md

Comment: Interesting.. I will check this tomorrow in the office,  thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try the solution from the link?

Comment: Yea, didn't really help me unfortunately. I am considering reinstalling that Mac or something :/